# Torchvision module not found in Python

Tags: pytorch, torchvision

My Python program can't find torchvision module to import even though it's installed.

I looked at the other posts for this problem on StackOverflow and none worked. I tried installing torchvision with conda and pip for Python 3.11 and nothing worked.

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/Users/my.name/miniconda3/envs/env_pytorch/lib/python3.11/site-packages/") 

import torch
import torchvision
from torchvision import models
```

results in

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/my.name/torchvision.py", line 5, in <module>
    import torchvision
  File "/Users/my.name/torchvision.py", line 6, in <module>
    from torchvision import models
ImportError: cannot import name 'models' from partially initialized module 'torchvision' (most likely due to a circular import) (/Users/my.name/torchvision.py)
```

I tried installing torchvision with conda and pip. Help!